# Everytime I draw list item in SFML it crashes?

Tags: c++, list, game-physics, sfml

So I am having a small issue with creating a list and having it write to my window using the SFML library. Basically what happens is that when I execute the fire() function the game freezes & crashes.

Variable code:

```
 sf::Sprite laser;
```

The list code is:

```
 std::list<sf::Sprite>laserList;
```

The fire code is (called when I click button):

```
 bool fire(void)
 {
   laserList.push_back(laser);
   return true;
 }
```

This is the drawing code to window:

```
//This is code for running through and drawing each sprite in list
for(std::list<sf::Sprite>::iterator it = laserList.begin(); it != laserList.end(); laserList;)
{
    app.draw(*it);
}
```

Comment: Where does `laser` from `laserList.push_back(laser);` come from?

Comment: @Quirliom that is the fire function that calls when I push the button. To my understanding that is how you push something into the list?

Comment: Yes but the question remains: What exactly are you pushing.

Comment: I am pushing the sprite laser into the list so I can draw the sprite later

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `for` loop is a bit strange here:

```
for(std::list<sf::Sprite>::iterator it = laserList.begin(); it != laserList.end(); laserList;)
```

You'll find that this will form an infinite loop as the value of `it` never changes. This may be what leads to your crash. To fix it you want to increment the iterator after every loop:

```
for(std::list<sf::Sprite>::iterator it = laserList.begin(); it != laserList.end(); ++laserList)
```

**There was an edit that suggested the following but was rejected for some reason. I have added it here for completeness**

You could avoid any confusion over this syntax by using the Range Based for loop introduced in C++11:

```
for(sf::Sprite spr : laserList){
    app.draw(spr);
}
```

Comment: &Quirliom Okay I have fixed that by adding it++ to go through the list correctly.

Comment: @user1626342 If it solves the question please accept the answer (when SO allows you to) to remove it from the unanswered questions list

Comment: Yup I will I can not select it for 3 more minutes! Thank you!